# How to optimize generation of unique combinations with varied weights in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I'm facing an optimization problem in Python where I aim to generate a large number of unique combinations (e.g. 10,000), with each combination being as distinct as possible from the others.

Here is a simplified version of my problem: I have a set of traits, where each trait can take on a certain number of variations. I want to create a set of unique combinations of these traits with maximized differences.

```py
traits = [ "trait1", "trait2", "trait3", ...]
traits_amounts = { "trait1" : value1, "trait2" : value2, "trait3" : value3, ...}
```

To quantify the differences, I've assigned a score to each trait, such that a higher score corresponds to a larger difference when that trait is changed. For instance, if I were to generate a new combination that differs from an existing one by changing `trait1`, the 'difference score' between the two combinations would be the score assigned to `trait1`.

```py
trait_score = { "trait1" : score1, "trait2" : score2, "trait3" : score3, ...}
```

My objective is to generate n combinations such that the 'difference score' between the least different combinations is as high as possible.

I tried finding an optimal solution using linear programming via Pulp. Unfortunately this problem seems to be exponentially hard and I think my best luck is to use a heuristic.

What approach can I take to solve this optimization problem? How can I efficiently generate these combinations in Python? Are there any libraries or algorithms that could be particularly useful for this situation?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How do you define the combinations ? Is it various amounts of all the traits or a selection of a certain number of traits ?   If a combination is aways all traits with varying amounts of each, how do you go from amount to score ? Is it  a multiplication or just that having a different amount gives a fixed score ?  It would help to have an example of two combinations with the difference calculation laid out

Comment: It is always all traits with one id for each in range [0, amount of the trait[. The differenciation score just works by summing. If I have A = { "trait1" : 0, "trait2" : 0, "trait3" : 0 }, then B = { "trait1" : 1, "trait2" : 1, "trait3" : 0 } could have a differenciation score of 3 if trait_score["trait1"] = 1 and trait_score["trait2"] = 2 for example.

Comment: This seems very approachable as a maxi-min assignment Linear Program.  You should use binary variables to indicate assignment of particular values from a trait set(s) and then use a variable to indicate the minimal difference score of all pairs and then maximize it.  Did you try something like that?  Can you post what you tried in `pulp`?

Comment: I am making the assumption (because it isn't stated clearly) that the values of the traits are given and that the task is assigning them to entities.

Comment: Are the trait values fixed and the traits selected or deselected during optimization? Or do the trait values vary during optimization?

Comment: OBTW...  just because the problem *can* be set up as an LP doesn't mean that is the best approach or that it is solvable in "reasonable" time.  Unless there is some natural pattern or further restriction for the traits that might guide a solution, solving for max separation of 10,000 entities in n-dimensional space is almost certainly intractable time-wise.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the total of trait values of all possible combinations, you will get a range form zero to the sum of maximum amounts.  By first selecting random combinations of totals in a way that ensures a minimum distance, you will get the required spacing.   For each of the selected totals there can be several combinations that match but you can only pick one (randomly).

So the process can be performed in two steps:

1. pick random total values spaced by a minimum difference
2. randomly pick a combination of traits that sum up to each of the selected totals

To do this, you'll need a few helper functions:

You'll need a function to pick a random trait combination with values that add up to a specific total:

```
from collections import Counter
def randTraits(total,valueRanges):
    indexes = []
    for i,r in enumerate(valueRanges):
        indexes += [i]*(r-1)
    result  = [0]*len(valueRanges)
    for i,n in Counter(random.sample(indexes,total)).items():
        result[i] = n
    return result
```

*Note: this function will give more weight to the larger maximum and tend to spread the total proportionally.  If that is not representative of what you are simulating, you can use a different distribution logic to better match you requirements.  The function may also be too slow if your traits value ranges are large*

In order to generate the random list of totals you can use a function that will randomly split a total value into a given number of parts (giving a list of gaps between totals to select):

```
def randSpread(total,count):
    result = [random.randrange(total+1) for _ in range(count)]
    tot    = sum(result)
    result = [ (total+1)*n//tot for n in result ]
    for _ in range(total-sum(result)):
        result[random.randrange(count)] += 1
    return result
```

The selection of random totals is actually built from a cumulative sum of individual gaps with a minimal gap size (minimum difference). The `randSpread` function is used to obtain the gaps between these cumulative totals (adding an extra gap from the edge of the range so that the last combinations is not always the one with all maximum values).

The minimum difference between trait combo totals subtracts from the range window of the random gaps (the minimum difference is added back in after obtaining the gap list).

```
from itertools import accumulate
def randCombos(traitsAmounts,comboCount,spacing=None):
    ranges  = traitsAmounts.values()
    scope   = sum(ranges)-len(ranges)
    spacing = spacing or scope//comboCount//2
    window  = scope - spacing*(comboCount-1)
    spread  = accumulate(randSpread(window-1,comboCount+1))
    combos  = [ c + spacing*i for i,c in enumerate(spread) ][:-1]
    result  = [ dict(zip(traitsAmounts,randTraits(tot,ranges)))
                for tot in combos ]
    return result
```

*Note: The function lets you specify what minimum spacing you want between combinations. Keep in mind that, the larger this spacing is, the less "random" the combinations are going to be because they will tend to align to specific positions in the range of total values.*

output:

```
traits_amounts = { "trait1" : 10, "trait2" : 100, "trait3" : 55}

combos = randCombos(traits_amounts,10,8)

for c in combos:
    print(sum(c.values()),c)

7 {'trait1': 1, 'trait2': 3, 'trait3': 3}
26 {'trait1': 2, 'trait2': 15, 'trait3': 9}
42 {'trait1': 1, 'trait2': 25, 'trait3': 16}
62 {'trait1': 6, 'trait2': 34, 'trait3': 22}
72 {'trait1': 6, 'trait2': 43, 'trait3': 23}
88 {'trait1': 3, 'trait2': 56, 'trait3': 29}
106 {'trait1': 7, 'trait2': 61, 'trait3': 38}
120 {'trait1': 9, 'trait2': 78, 'trait3': 33}
135 {'trait1': 9, 'trait2': 83, 'trait3': 43}
153 {'trait1': 9, 'trait2': 93, 'trait3': 51}
```

The combinations are random but they are produced in ascending order of their total traits values.  If you need the order to also be randomized, you can shuffle the resulting list:

```
random.shuffle(combos)
print(*combos,sep="\n")

{'trait1': 7, 'trait2': 61, 'trait3': 38}
{'trait1': 3, 'trait2': 56, 'trait3': 29}
{'trait1': 2, 'trait2': 15, 'trait3': 9}
{'trait1': 1, 'trait2': 3, 'trait3': 3}
{'trait1': 6, 'trait2': 34, 'trait3': 22}
{'trait1': 6, 'trait2': 43, 'trait3': 23}
{'trait1': 1, 'trait2': 25, 'trait3': 16}
{'trait1': 9, 'trait2': 93, 'trait3': 51}
{'trait1': 9, 'trait2': 78, 'trait3': 33}
{'trait1': 9, 'trait2': 83, 'trait3': 43}
```

This solution still has room for optimization (especially `randTraits`) which may be required depending on the ranges of trait amounts and the number of traits.

Performance for 10,000 combinations of 50 traits with amounts between 100 and 500:

```
from time import time

traits = {str(n):random.randrange(100,500) for n in range(50)}

start = time()
combos = randCombos(traits,10000)

print(time()-start) # 53 seconds
```